# Extending treelist having issues with token resolver

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, datasource

I am following this article to extend treelist field - https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/01/06/specifying-query-and-parameters-for-sitecore-treelist-field-source/.

We want to have a treelist field with support of query and other datasource parameters. But adding a query with token is causing issue.
This query is working - `datasource=query:$site/Data/Topic`
Whereas this is not - `datasource=query:$sharedSites/Data/Topic`

This is because `$sharedSites` token is getting converted to lowercase and its not getting resolved. Do we have any way of handling this with modifying the query?

Comment: What version of Sitecore you have?

Comment: Its Sitecore 10.1

Comment: In the article, you are following they are using `CompareCaseInsensitive` method for this. Did you try?

Comment: Yeah...seems like that is for comparing two variables there. Not working with token

Comment: If you are using this in SXA you might want to read https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2020/10/sxa-tokens-in-sitecore-treelist.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking at this it is because in the treelist SetProperties it sets the Datasource to LowerInvariant

Something like this should work

```
private string CasedDataSource => StringUtil.ExtractParameter("DataSource", this.Source).Trim();
```

and use that for all additional logic

Comment: Thank you, Matt